# Remove drag property from uploaded image in canvas html5 (set area to uploaded image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric js for uploading image in canvas. Right now it is a draggable, But i want to remove drag property and set area to uploaded image on canvas.

HTML:

```
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
        <input type="file" id="file">
```

CSS:

```
 canvas{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
```

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
            document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (f) {
                    var data = f.target.result;
                    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
                        var oImg = img.set({left: 50, top: 100,width: 250, height: 200, angle: 00}).scale(0.9);
                        canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
                        var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
                    });

                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                    format: 'png',
                    opacity: 0.9
                });

            });
```

```js
 
 
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
            document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (f) {
                    var data = f.target.result;
                    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
                        var oImg = img.set({left: 50, top: 100,width:200,height:200, angle: 00}).scale(0.9);
                        canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
                        var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
                    });

                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                    format: 'png',
                    opacity: 0.9
                });
                console.log("Canvas Image " + dataURL);
            });
```

```css
 canvas{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
```

```html
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
        <input type="file" id="file">
```

I want remove only drag property of uploaded image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just lock it with

```
.lockMovementX = true;
.lockMovementY = true;
```

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
            document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (f) {
                    var data = f.target.result;
                    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
                        var oImg = img.set({left: 50, top: 100,width:200,height:200, angle: 00}).scale(0.9);
                        oImg.lockMovementX = true;
                        oImg.lockMovementY = true;
                        canvas.add(oImg);
                        var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
                    });

                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                    format: 'png',
                    opacity: 0.9
                });
                console.log("Canvas Image " + dataURL);
            });
```

```css
canvas{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
        <input type="file" id="file">
```

Comment: Can we lock increase the width?

Comment: .lockScalingX = true :)

Comment: It is right.Thanks. Can we add zoom this image. But spread area. It should be spread exist area.

Comment: please use this website as it shoudl be used. If you have a different question, open another question, Me or someone else will help you again. If we put answers in comments no one is gonna find them and this effort is wasted.